# How to draw route on map with KMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, routes, mkmapview

I am parsing a kml file using KMLParser in my application. When i open the kml file in google map it shows me the route with annotations & overlay's. My query is

1) Is it possible to get the route data from kml to draw the route on map

2) If not how can i achieve route drawing from kml file

Any suggestion or hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can get the route data from the KML-file using KMLParser, as I'm not sure what features that parser provides. An alternative to using KMLParser would be to simply parse the KML-file yourself, using for example KissXML och GDataXML. If you only need the route information from the KML-file, using a plain XML-parser might be simpler.

You need to parse the data and then translate it into something you can draw on the map, like CLLocationCoordinate2D. Once you have your data as an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D-coordinates, you can follow this tutorial for learning how to draw a line on a map: http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial Specifically the section "I Walk The Line – MKPolyline".

Good luck!